# Graphs subdivision and smoothing in networkx

Tags: networkx

I have a graph with very few critical points, and I would like to add many more redundant nodes between them. So if I have A->B->C, I'd like to get A->A0->A1->A2->B->B0->B1-B2->C

The intermediate nodes should be on the same linear edge between A->B and B->C.

It looks like the operation is called [subdivision and smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing). Is there a way to do it using networkx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Graph.add_path?

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_edge('A','B')

In [4]: G.add_path(['A','A0','A1','A2','B'])

In [5]: G.remove_edge('A','B')

In [6]: G.edges()
Out[6]: [('A', 'A0'), ('A0', 'A1'), ('B', 'A2'), ('A1', 'A2')]
```